# Which way of rendering objects in OpenGL is more efficient?

Tags: c++, opengl, gpu

Which way of rendering two graphic elements with the same shape but different coordinates is more efficient using OpenGL (for eg. one object is upside down)?

1. Generate two different sets of points using CPU and then use only one shader in while loop
2. Generate only one set of points using CPU, create two different shaders and then switch between them in the while loop?

Additional question: Is there a possibility to create a set of points inside a shader? (This points will be calculated using `sin()` and `cos()` functions)

Comment: Why would you need two sets of vertices or two shaders? You can draw both objects using the same vertices and the same shader.

Comment: How about: Create one set of points and one shader and use a transformation to specify where it should be placed?

Comment: Hmm transormations... Maybe this is a good idea but my question is still active - I just want to know how it looks like in theory - just for my awareness ;)

Comment: @S.Seba: regarding the transformation: Note that you may also pass extra parameters to the shader, so that the transformation may also be achieved without setting it directly.

Comment: @S.Seba: anyway, if you talk "theoretically". Assuming you either load 2 sets of vertexes into GPU, or 2 shader programs - I believe there won't be much difference once it all in the GPU (i.e. vertexes are uploaded and shaders are compiled). Shader occupy less space, so it's better to save memory. But, of course, the best solution is to use the transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in the first case you're switching buffers between OpenGL function calls then probably both solutions are equally bad. If you're holding two shapes in a single buffer and drawing everything in a single call then it's going to be faster than solution 2, but it requires twice the memory, which is also bad.
( You should have a single buffer for the shape and another one for transformations )
In general, you should use as few OpenGL calls as possible.

Regarding the second question: yes. For example, you could use a hard-coded array or derive the point coordinates from gl_VertexID.

Comment: Thanks everyone for answeres. My question is now resolved.